# "She wanted out of this dump." What is the grammatical function of "out of this dump"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, register, transitivity, grammatical-roles

I came across a line in a movie.

> **She wanted out of this dump**. She wanted to start a new life.

It seems the sentence is missing *to get/be/go*. Is the sentence grammatical as it currently stands?

Since *want* is a transitive verb, it takes a direct object (noun/NP/to infinitive). The phrase *out of this dump* is adverbial. So is the sentence ungrammatical = informal in register?

Comment: You seem to be parsing this as [She wanted][out of this dump]. I’d probably parse it more like [She wanted out][of this dump].

Comment: @J.R. That makes perfect sense. "She wants out." sounds more familiar and idiomatic to me. Is _out_ a noun here then?

Comment: @L.Moneta "want" is not only a transitive verb. Take for example: I want to leave early. I think "wanted out of" is an intransitive phrasal verb like these: The police were called to **break up** the fight. When the door is opened, it **sets off** an alarm.

Comment: "Want" is used intransitively here. "Out of this dump" is probably best analysed as a reduced clause, typically used in casual speech. In full it would be something like "She wanted [to be out of this dump]", where the bracketed element is a catenative complement of "wanted".

Comment: aesking and BillJ Thank you both. I understand "want out" as a phrasal verb is intransitive. However, the word **want** is listed as transitive, also on [the Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/want_1). Also, [@tchrist's answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/434804/253154) seems to suggest infinitives are substantives and thus count as direct objects. I am confused.

Comment: @L.Moneta *almost* any verb can be used transitively or intransitively. It depends on the context of the sentence. If you check [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want), it has both. It is not only the the phrasal verb that is transitive, the verb "want" by itself can be transitive or intransitive, and intransitive in: [I want to leave early] in the earlier example.

Comment: To "want out of something/somewhere" is certainly idiomatic. But I tend to think of it as "She wanted[to get] out of this dump" i.e. an acceptable elision of part of the object clause.

Comment: to want out [of a place] is a phrasal verb plus a prepositional phrase. A phrasal verb is a verb + a preposition taken as a single unit of meaning: to want out, to give up, to wind down

Comment: @L.Moneta In, "your bad habit is to smoke/to drink alcohol", are the infinitives to smoke and to drink objects? Similarly, in "To err is human, to forgive divine" (as WS2 exemplifies [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389720/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-to-verb)) are the to-phrases objects?

Comment: @aesking There’s never any object in a copula like those you just asked about.  This is because there is no transitive verb to deliver its action to any object. There’s just a nominal acting as the subject on one side of the copula(r verb) and a predicative expression of one or another sort on the other side. The predicate can be another nominal (infinitives can be nominals) but can also be an adjective or adjective phrase, or a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Why does everyone complicate this type of question so much? The parse is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/want-out) exemplifies the phrasal verb "want out" as **intransitive** in the following sentences:

> Would you open the door? The dog **wants out**.

> She **wanted out** of the jail cell so badly she started to scream.

"Of" is not a part of the phrasal verb as the phrasal verb "want out" can be replaced with "get out" in:

> 1. He [got out] of jail
> 2. He [want out] of jail

Note 2 is ungrammatical because it would have to be he *wants* or *wanted* (to signify a different tense), notice the difference between *He **wants** out of jail* and *He **wanted** out of jail.*

The expression is certainly idiomatic/informal but that doesn't necessarily warrant ungrammaticalness.

---

ODO cites:

> Phrasal verbs can be *intransitive* (i.e. they have no object):
>
> We **broke up** [two years ago].
>
> They **set off** [early to miss the traffic].
>
> He **pulled up** [outside the cottage].
>
> *The things in [] are not objects. They can be omitted and still be grammatically and semantically complete.*

> or *transitive* (i.e. they can have an object):
>
> The police were called to **break up** the fight.
>
> When the door is opened, it **sets off** an alarm.
>
> They **pulled** the house **down** and redeveloped the site.
>
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79747/discussion-on-answer-by-aesking-she-wanted-out-of-this-dump-what-is-the-gramm).

Comment: The reverse preposition works as well: "You're having a card game tonight? I want in."

Answer (score 1):

Sample sentence: 
She wanted out || of this dump||. That is my parse.

***To want out*** is a phrasal verb meaning: to not want to be in a place or relationship. It can be followed by a prepositional phrase or not.

The opposite also exists: **to want in**, meaning: to want to be a part of something.

**They were playing poker and I wanted in** [to the game].

To want out + of this dump is a phrasal verb + a prepositional phrase.'

In English, you are in or out of a place or relationship. And you can want in or into a place or relationship.

The cat wanted out of the house. = The cat did not want to be in the house. or: The cat wanted to go out of the house.

For me: to want in/into or want out (to desire to come, go or be or the negative of that: Merriam Webster,  ***intransitive***) can be followed by prepositional phrases that act as a complement to the idiomatic usage of the verbs.

[Intransitive](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/intransitive-verbs.html) verbs can be followed by a prepositional phrase or an adverb to add to the thought being expressed, but they can never be followed by a noun, which would act as the object of the sentence.

"of this dump" is a prepositional phrase that adds to the thought being expressed. Here, expressing the place or location from which relief is sought.

Answer (score 1):

The OED includes it under their sense 13 of *want* - a "colloquial" form.

> 13. intr. colloq. (orig. regional, esp. Sc. and U.S.). With adverb and ellipsis of the infinitive, as to want away, to want home, to want
>       off, etc. To wish to go to or from a particular place; to wish to be
>       in or out of a particular situation. Recorded earliest in to want in
>       at Phrases 5a; **see also to want out at Phrases 5b**.
>
> 1979   New Pittsburgh Courier 4 Aug. (Entertainer section) 4/3   There
>   are the two good ole boys from Atlanta who want in on the bust out.
>
> 2000   J. J. Connolly Layer Cake (2004) 222   We did do a bit of
>   junior time together but I always wanted away.